# Creating a range across a group of arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, range, enumeration

In my search controller I've gathered a list of results (artists/albums) using the `group_by` method.

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @grouped_results = @results.group_by { |q| q.class.name }
  end
end
```

In my view the `@grouped_results` are enumerated and placed in divs according to the class they belong to (artists/albums).

```
<% @grouped_results.each do |class_name, results| %>
  <div class="<%= class_name.downcase %>-results">
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What I'd like to do is take the first 10 results from each group. So it would return up to 10 artists and also return up to 10 albums. With this in mind the `take` method or using a numeric range (`0..10`) won't suffice since I'm essentially trying to do this with 2 arrays. What would be the best approach to getting this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get the 10 first results in your loop:

```
<% @grouped_results.each do |class_name, results| %>
  <% few_first_results = results[0..9] %>
  # etc.
  <% few_first_results.each do |result| %>
    # etc.
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: But wouldn't that grab the first 10 results across both instead of the first 10 for **each** of the two arrays?

Comment: Try it and you will see the result ;-) It will just take the first ten results, finish the loop, go to the next key in the Hash, and then grab the first ten results of this key, etc etc. It should do what you are trying to achieve